# Changing my BigQuery tables' names (Exported from Stackdriver)

Tags: google-bigquery, stackdriver

I have a backend (Node JS) app hosted on GCP compute engine that exports logs to Google BigQuery by means of sinks from Stackdriver. 
I have two sinks: 
   1-One for driver location logs
   2-One for authentication logs
The problem is that the BigQuery table name is picked by default (using the logName attribute in the logs) and knowing that all my logs have the same logName attribute value, Only one table is created. so the second sink is not creating any table in BigQuery.
Is there another way to create tables and assign them to sinks ?

-I tried to add logName attribute to the logs of my source code (using Bunyan library) but the attribute appears inside jsonPayload instead of outside that object, so it does not make any difference.
-I tried to create a dataset for each sink which worked but it is a not a proper thing do do.

Comment: You cannot customize the table name created by logging sinks. As you said, you can separate the logs but using 2 different datasets. Why you want the log to stay into a single dataset but in separate tables?

Comment: That is what i thought. But it is crucial to have multiple schemas in our case knowing  that some fields won't be available at first. and this would be fatale (future logs that have new attributes won't be validated by #BigQuery). is there a way to create tables manually and assign them to sinks. or at least other google solutions to relate logs to specific manually created tables?

Comment: If your worry is adding a new column to existing tables, BigQuery supports that. You can add it manually from the UI, programmatically, or create the table with the setting that will create a field if not existing (I think). I would test your scenario to be sure but you can definitely add a column. If you need to add a field to a record this might not be possible by a schema update. But you could run a query with destination table and modify the schema in the select. This might not be a scalable solution if you have frequent schema changes.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. i will be back with more details and questions

Comment: Well, concerning creating a table that will create a field if not existing. I have not found any param to do so. Besides, the table is created automatically and assigned automatically. so, i tried adding attributes to the table but knowing that Stackdriver fields are all in jsonPayload, adding a field means adding a column jsonPayload.field_name and the column name can't have dots in it. what do you think i should do ?

Comment: Yes, you cannot add a field inside a record column but only a "root" column. I think that your best bet is having your JSON payload as a JSON string so you can put any JSON string inside with any field at any time. This will make the analytics a bit more complicated because you will need to use JSON functions to extract column at query runtime. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions

Comment: Thanks, i have found a work around. when adding new attributes, i will make a copy of that day table, the copy name will be postfixed with '_old' and remove the old table. and then the new logs would create that table with the new attribute added. I am looking for other solutions like workflow and cloud functions but the cost will double if i use them.

Comment: That's the other solution I proposed in a previous comment. Be careful that this might break your query logic when querying multiple days (using wildcard). If you reference a column that does not exist in a table the query will not run.